# Turn days into weeks, months, years.ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have this query and result:

```
SQL> select AVG(SYSDATE - DOB) AS AVERAGE_AGE_IN_DAYS
  2  FROM MORTAL;

AVERAGE_AGE_IN_DAYS
-------------------
           17877.44
```

Is there a way to convert this to years, months, and days, within the same query?

Comment: There is a ton of information here - http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html

Comment: How are you defining "month", 30 days, 31 days? Same with year. I'm not sure your question even has a definite answer.

Comment: Im defining 'year' as 365 days. Thats the best I can do,

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of months you could use [months_between](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm)

```
SELECT select AVG(months_between(SYSDATE,DOB)) AS AVERAGE_AGE_IN_MONTHS
```

For years, just do months_between/12

```
SELECT select AVG(months_between(SYSDATE,DOB)/12) AS AVERAGE_AGE_IN_YEARS
```

For weeks, i would just take your result for days and divide it by 7.

You might have to handle the results to fit your needs, but i think this should cover it.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
select 
floor(months_between(SYSDATE,DOB)/12) AS years,
trunc( months_between(SYSDATE,DOB) ) AS months, 
SYSDATE - add_months( SYSDATE, trunc(months_between(SYSDATE,DOB)) ) AS days
```

This is years,months,days as the detail suggests.  The title said weeks too but I'm not if you actually want them.

Comment: This wouldnt work, oracle (at least my version of it, 11g) doesn't recognize 'dt2' in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your query would be:

```
with dates as (select AVG(SYSDATE - DOB) as d --average_in_days
                 from MORTAL
              )
select trunc(d/365) as years
     , trunc((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12 ) as months
     , trunc((((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12) - trunc((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12 )) * 4.348214) as weeks     
     , trunc(((((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12) - trunc((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12 )) * 4.348214
                       - trunc((((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12) - trunc((d/365 - trunc(d/365)) * 12 )) * 4.348214 )
             ) * 7 
             ) as days     
from dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION time_spell(p_days VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_y NUMBER;
v_yd NUMBER;
v_m NUMBER;
v_md NUMBER;
v_d NUMBER;
v_w NUMBER;
v_wd NUMBER;
v_days NUMBER;
v_yi NUMBER;
v_mi NUMBER;
v_wi  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT p_days/365 INTO v_y FROM dual;

if v_y not like '%.%' then
SELECT trunc(v_y) INTO v_yi FROM dual;
select substr(v_y||'.0',(select instr(v_y||'.0','.') from dual)) INTO v_yd from dual;
SELECT v_yd * 12 INTO v_m FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_m) INTO v_mi FROM dual;
select substr(v_m,(select instr(v_m,'.') from dual)) INTO v_md from dual;
SELECT v_md * 30 INTO v_d FROM dual;
SELECT v_d / 7 INTO v_w FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_w) INTO v_wi FROM dual;
select substr(v_w,(select instr(v_w,'.') from dual)) INTO v_wd from dual;
SELECT round(v_wd * 7) INTO v_days FROM dual;
RETURN v_yi||' Year(s) '||v_mi||' Month(s) '||v_wi||' Week(s) '||v_days||' Day(s) ';
else
SELECT trunc(v_y) INTO v_yi FROM dual;
select substr(v_y,(select instr(v_y,'.') from dual)) INTO v_yd from dual;
SELECT v_yd * 12 INTO v_m FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_m) INTO v_mi FROM dual;
select substr(v_m,(select instr(v_m,'.') from dual)) INTO v_md from dual;
SELECT v_md * 30 INTO v_d FROM dual;
SELECT v_d / 7 INTO v_w FROM dual;
SELECT trunc(v_w) INTO v_wi FROM dual;
select substr(v_w,(select instr(v_w,'.') from dual)) INTO v_wd from dual;
SELECT round(v_wd * 7) INTO v_days FROM dual;
RETURN v_yi||' Year(s) '||v_mi||' Month(s) '||v_wi||' Week(s) '||v_days||' Day(s) ';
end if;
END;
```

[SELECT time_spell(17877.44) FROM dual;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB4N9.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).